# Android selector with fade in / fade out duration initially invisible

Tags: android, android-drawable

I'm trying to achieve that an icon in ActionBar will not change states discretely, but by fading animation. When I add `android:enterFadeDuration` and `android:exitFadeDuration` to the selector tag, my drawable is initially *invisible* - when I tap it, it changes state to `state_pressed` (properly with enter fade duration) and when I release it, it turns back to its normal visible unselected state.

I must be missing something obvious, or is this a bug of some kind?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:enterFadeDuration="150" android:exitFadeDuration="150">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/filters_toggle_icon_selected" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/filters_toggle_icon_selected" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/filters_toggle_icon" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: So did you find solution?

Comment: I would also be curious if you found a solution.

My best workaround so far is to remove all `fadeDuration` parameters.

Comment: The problem seems to exist **only on API 23** when using fade animations. I am having the same problem (I'm using a selector as compound drawable for a `TextView`) and ended up using a selector without animations on API 23. 
I tested the behaviour on versions 21-27.

Answer (score 7):

I had a **similar problem**, with my code looking like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          android:enterFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
          android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/default" />
</selector>
```

At first, I found a hint to get rid of `enterFadeDuration` and only use `exitFadeDuration`. That solved the problem with initial invisibility, but the view still faded into invisibility during the first interraction.

Then, I **modified** my structure as follows:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/default" />
    <item>
        <selector android:enterFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
                  android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" >
            <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/pressed" />
        </selector>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Basically, I just pushed the default drawable out of the selector. It's a workaround and it also works for selectors with multiple states, but has some **notable limitations:**

- The **default drawable** is **always visible** as a bottom layer. It works for opaque colors, but transparency may cause undesirable results.
- If the view **starts** in one of the states tested by selector, in still displays **as default**, because the selector still starts as invisible.

It **might not be applicable** to the original problem, but it's something to consider for overcoming this behaviour of selectors.

Answer (score 3):

Use `android:enterFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"` and `android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"`.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was similar as well, the issue was that after setting a background drawable on my view, it was in the wrong state (sometimes it even mixed the stroke and solid of two states...). This was only before the first interaction, like receiving focus or changing enabled state.

I've found that if you call `jumpToCurrentState()` on the drawable (which has the fade duration properties) after setting it on the view, it will be set on the correct state, and you can keep on using the enter / exit fade duration properties.
Here's how I did it:

```
val stateList = (darkBackground as? RippleDrawable)?.findDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.background) as? StateListDrawable
background = darkBackground
stateList?.jumpToCurrentState()
```

In this example I had a ripple drawable which contained the selector which had the fade properties (I had to add an ID to the selector so I could look it up using the ID).

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be a bug that happens on specific Android versions. You can turn off the `android:enterFadeDuration` programmatically in Java code, by accessing the [Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32226232/android-create-selector-programmatically) with a [StateListDrawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26713618/get-specific-drawable-from-state-list-drawable):

```
// Disable android:enterFadeDuration/exitFadeDuration on Android 4.2 only
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    StateListDrawable stateListDrawable =
            (StateListDrawable) animatedButton.getBackground();
    stateListDrawable.setEnterFadeDuration(0);
    stateListDrawable.setExitFadeDuration(0);
}
```